# columns to rows change in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have columns a,b in table x.And i want to change this columns data into rows.
it is possible to have duplicate vales  in table but in columns to row change only distinct values should come.

```
E.G:
a    b
1    2
1    11
3    4
5    6
7    8
9    10
......etc
```

the `result 1 (query 1) should be 1-2,1-11,3-4,5-6,7-8,9-10.....`etc

The `result 2 (query 2) should b 1,3,5,7,9....`etc(only one 1 must come as we have duplicate data for column a)

how can i achieve this in oracle SQL.

Please help.

Comment: You are looking for pivot. Take a look here: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506

Comment: thanks for the document.however how can i achieve the result format which i mentioned in the query.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 11 use function [listagg()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm#SQLRF30030) and in first query concatenate columns, in second - select distinct values at first.

Query 1:

```
select listagg(a||'-'||b, ',') within group (order by a, b) result from t

RESULT
------------------------------
1-2,1-11,3-4,5-6,7-8,9-10
```

Query 2:

```
select listagg(a, ',') within group (order by a) result 
  from (select distinct a from t)

RESULT
------------------------------
1,3,5,7,9
```

For older versions you can use [wmsys.wm_concat](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#wm_concat).

Comment: thanks.if i need to select column c,d, along with the result how can modify both the qury.as when i tried m facing error.

Comment: I need to see your modified query and error details, please provide this info, otherwise I'm not able to help.